# Possible scam call from a "Microsoft maintenance service representative"

Tags: windows, security

I got a call from someone claiming to be from Microsoft maintenance service, telling me that he was receiving messages from my computer that there was a virus. There were several pop-up message alerts and he asked me to call the 800 number. I changed my pop-up blocker to "high" and no more "alert" messages have appeared.

Has the Microsoft maintenance service really called me or has someone tried to make money? A few months ago, a similar thing happened and I called. It ended up that he asked me to pay $159, and when I refused, he offered a discounted amount of $79, which I also refused. But my computer was messed up because I allowed him to invade my computer. I think he broke my computer because I did not pay.

What should I do? Has my computer really been hacked into, or was he an impostor?

Comment: Microsoft does not, has not, will not ever contact you unless you contact them.  They do not, have not, and will not have the man power to call you and tell you that you have a virus on your computer.  You have been scammed by criminals.  If you allowed him access to your computer, your only real option, is to format your machine and reinstall the operating system.

Comment: It sounds like a scam. I would suggest you use Microsoft Security Essentials ([MSE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download)) or [MBAM](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) to scan you computer.

Comment: I live by a simple rule, I NEVER allow ANYONE to connect to my machine.

Comment: They mess up (infect) your computer whether or not you pay.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what Microsoft has to say about such calls at [Avoid tech support phone scams](https://www.microsoft.com/security/online-privacy/avoid-phone-scams.aspx):

> Cybercriminals don't just send fraudulent email messages and set up
>   fake websites. They might also call you on the telephone and claim to
>   be from Microsoft. They might offer to help solve your computer
>   problems or sell you a software license. ... Neither Microsoft nor our
>   partners make unsolicited phone calls (also known as cold calls) to
>   charge you for computer security or software fixes. Cybercriminals
>   often use publicly available phone directories, so they might know
>   your name and other personal information when they call you. They
>   might even guess what operating system you're using.

The page I reference on Microsoft's website provides information on reporting such calls. I'd also refer you to an article at the ABC News website titled [Beware Cyber Scammers Posing as Tech Support](http://abcnews.go.com/Blotter/beware-cyber-scammers-disguised-tech-support/story?id=22805671) which starts with a report received by ABC News Fixer from someone who actually runs a computer repair shop relating an experience of one of his clients, which begins with:

> **Dear ABC News Fixer:** I think you should let your viewers know about an ongoing scam, in which someone calls and claims to be with
>   Windows or Microsoft, telling you they have detected a virus or a
>   malfunction in your computer. They ask you to log into a website and
>   then they plant a real virus or malware in your computer and hold you
>   hostage for absurd fees to remove it.

His client, who was taken in by the ruse, was an adjunct professor at a prestigious business school. I've had people for whom I provide computer support tell me they've received such calls and my wife has also received them; one time she had me pick up the phone and I talked to the scammer, who didn't seem to have any real technical knowledge, just a script. And at the beginning of this month I received a call from someone I once worked with who is now retired. He didn't give the "technician" a credit card number, but did let him in to "check" his computer. I would offer you the same advice I gave him that the safest course at this point would be to wipe out the operating system and reinstall it and all applications, but at least check the system with antivirus and antispyware programs. There are free versions of programs such as [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/), [SUPERAntispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/), [Spybot - Search & Destroy](https://www.safer-networking.org/), etc. that, because they don't run constantly, but only on-demand, e.g., only when you manually run them, shouldn't conflict with any existing antivirus software you may have on the system.

Answer (score 3):

He was an imposter and loaded your computer with spyware.  Your best bet is to reset the system to factory defaults and start fresh.  Backup your documents and use the built in recovery or recovery disks, whichever your PC has.